# Security Groups for AWS: why only other SGs as source?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spinnaker

I am running Spinnaker on AWS to deploy resources in AWS. When adding a new rule to a security group, I can only choose other, existing security groups as source. However, sometimes I would like to allow access to my AWS resources also from other sources, e.g. 0.0.0.0/0 for a public load balancer. I can add this rule in the AWS console, which is then displayed as "ip range rules" in Spinnaker, but cannot add such a rule using the Spinnaker UI.

Is there a reason why this is not supported in Spinnaker or is this just a not-yet-implemented feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We originally included the ability to add IP ingress rules in Spinnaker, but, after a couple of folks created inappropriately large ranges, we were asked to remove the functionality from the UI by our security teams.

The backend API still supports it, so there's no reason it couldn't be exposed through the UI via a feature flag, if someone wanted to re-implement it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, makes sense to me. It's probably advisable to restrict modifying operations that are security-related (or at least make them harder to access). Also, because these operations are potentially executed by users that do not have (modifying) access to the underlying AWS account.